# SQLite запись из 2х соединений к одну базу. Либо запись в асинхронном варианте базы

Tags: sqlite3, асинхронность

На сколько я знаю и понимаю из [документации](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html), SQLite не поддерживает асинхронной записи верно ? Т.е. если открывать с флагом "Serialized" - то база просто будет лочиться при каждом обращении из каждого потока, если же "Single-thread" или "Multi-thread" - то синхронизатор доступа не создается вовсе как я вижу из кода базы и получается что каждое соединение думает что оно уникально.

Соответственно, мы можем либо создать одно соединение на запись и кучу на чтение по одному в каждом потоке (с флагом "Multi-thread"), либо одно соединение с флагом "Serialized" и тогда бутылочным горлышком будет не только запись но и чтение в том числе верно ?

Comment: Посмотрите тут похожий вопрос 
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1355616/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8c-%d0%b2-sqlite3-python/1355732#1355732

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте установить параметр соединения check_same_thread=False https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

> По умолчанию check_same_thread есть, True и только создающий поток
> может использовать соединение. Если установлено False, возвращенное
> соединение может совместно использоваться несколькими потоками. При
> использовании нескольких потоков с одним и тем же соединением операции
> записи должны быть сериализованы пользователем, чтобы избежать
> повреждения данных