# Как создать очередь в SQLite3 Python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3, асинхронность

*Работаю в асинхронном боте*

На сколько знаю в **SQLite3** читать можно одновременно, но редактировать только одним потоком.

Можно ли как-то **создать очередь**, чтобы не появлялось исключение "database is locked"?

Видел похоже асинхронный **SQLite3**, но мне нужно возвращать его ответы и не думаю, что это решит проблему.

Comment: может просто использовать другой инструмент?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте установить параметр соединения check_same_thread=False
https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html

> По умолчанию check_same_thread есть, True и только создающий поток может использовать соединение. Если установлено False, возвращенное соединение может совместно использоваться несколькими потоками. При использовании нескольких потоков с одним и тем же соединением операции записи должны быть сериализованы пользователем, чтобы избежать повреждения данных